# Batch Echoing from Lateral to Horizontal

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I have the following issue: A regular list with this approximate information:

```
Computer1
DateImplemented
Computer2
DateImplemented
Computer3
DateImplemented
<this goes on for a while>
```

What I want it do do:

```
Computer1,DateImplemented
Computer2,DateImplemented
<etc>
```

I have been trying a bunch of ways but the only output I get is:

```
Computer1
DateImplemented.
```

This is going to be one of those 50-50 scenarios where the solution is stupidly easy or stupidly hard.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. Questions must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it _should_ work. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set computer=
for /F "delims=" %%a in (list.txt) do (
   if not defined computer (
      set "computer=%%a"
   ) else (
      echo !computer!,%%a
      set computer=
   )
)
```

As usual, this Batch flile may be modified to manage special Batch characters, if required.

Comment: Thank you guys very much. Now i know how to finally do this. :)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set LINENUM=0
set PREVLINE=
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type list.txt') do (
  set /a LINENUM+=1
  set CURRLINE=%%a
  set /a REMAINDER=!LINENUM! %% 2
  if !REMAINDER! EQU 0 echo !PREVLINE!,!CURRLINE!
  set PREVLINE=!CURRLINE!
)
endlocal
```

(Assuming your data is in list.txt, of course)

Comment: +1, works good, except for exclams `!` and empty lines, but this can be fixed if needed.

Comment: Correct--this script won't work if the input file contains empty lines or characters that require escaping. PowerShell would be a better choice.

Comment: Escaping is not the point, it works with `&><|%^`, `delayed expansion` kills the exclams `!` and the `for` loop the empty lines. And this can be fixed in batch. You can toggeling the `delayed expansion` and fill empty lines with line numbers (can be removed later).

Comment: Modulo operator determines if current line number is odd or even.